# R package compilation problem due to LAPACK on Ubuntu 20.04 after upgrade from 18.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, lapack, rcpparmadillo

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and now some of my R packages fail to compile/load. One example is shown below:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'myPackage' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-my_package/00new/myPackage/libs/myPackage.so':
  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-my_package/00new/myPackge/libs/myPackage.so: undefined symbol: dgesvx_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

This `dgesvx_` looks like a LAPACK problem (https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga9d90ccf6e340cacd08b7bbbb502ceb21.html#ga9d90ccf6e340cacd08b7bbbb502ceb21).

And I have latest LAPACK version available in Ubuntu 20.04 installed (3.9.0-1build1).

What can I do here to resolve the problem?

My `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2
```

Comment: Perhaps https://gist.github.com/GjjvdBurg/2e5a9d460557d6b267985eb8516472a1 (not in R, unfortunately).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @MarioBecerra If my memory serves me well Dirk Eddelbuettel provided a solution for this problem here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2020-October/003258.html

Comment: In the end I got it working by updating most of my R packages :)

Comment: Okay, I ran into the same problem again, and now I had to use Dirk's solution in the link you suggested and it worked.